# Internet Explorer broken image icon but photo works

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, umbraco, microsoft-edge

For some reason Internet Explorer is showing the photo's but also showing the broken photo icon on top. Is this because of something in my code? Is it because I am using razor script along with Umbraco? I don't understand why it's there, it works for every browser except Edge and Internet Explorer

[image]

Here's the code in case something I did is wrong.

```
<section class="block block__media">
    <div class="container" style="margin-top:-8%;">
        <div class="rowPhotos">
            <div class="PhotoRight">
                <h5>@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("PhotoRightTitle")</h5><br>
                <a target="_blank" href="@Umbraco.Media(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("PhotoExtraRight").ToString()).Url"><img src="@Umbraco.Media(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("PhotoExtraRight").ToString()).Url?h=250&w=450" alt="@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("PhotoRightTitle")" /></a>
                <p class="ExtraPhotoText"><br>@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("PhotoRightText")</p>
            </div>

            <h5>@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("PhotoLeftTitle")</h5><br>
            <a target="_blank" href="@Umbraco.Media(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("PhotoExtraLeft").ToString()).Url"><img src="@Umbraco.Media(Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("PhotoExtraLeft").ToString()).Url?h=250" alt="@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("PhotoLeftTitle")" /></a>
            <p class="ExtraPhotoText"><br>@Model.Content.GetPropertyValue("PhotoLeftText")</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Edit

Even with images from placeholder it shows broken icon

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/57u1w98h/ with the placeholder images.

```css
.PhotoRight {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 0.7%;
}

.PhotoLeft {
  margin-left: 1%;
}

.RowPhotos {
  margin-left: 0.1%;
}

.ExtraPhotoText {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: #5d5d5d;
}
```

```html
<section class="block block__media">
  <div class="container" style="margin-top:-8%;">
    <div class="rowPhotos">
      <div class="PhotoRight">
        <h5>Temp Title</h5><br>
        <a target="_blank" href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?h=250&w=450" alt="Temp alt" /></a>a
        <p class="ExtraPhotoText"><br>Temp text</p>
      </div>

      <h5>temp title 2</h5><br>
      <a target="_blank" href="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150?h=250" alt="temp alt" /></a>
      <p class="ExtraPhotoText"><br>temp text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Edit:

Found two broken images but they're not in my code, I'll start digging into this. Thanks for idea.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps post the rendered HTML from view-source with placeholder.com images?

Comment: Done but that gave the same outcome.

Comment: Have you inspected HTML to see if that is not some other images, not in your sample code?

Comment: @Justinas You're right, I actually didn't think of that >.< Apparently there's something there called nothing.jpg?? I don't see it in my code but it must be there somewhere, I also noticed that Chrome is showing 1 error in dev mode which is that nothing.jpg picture. I'll find the code somewhere (maybe one of my partial views or javascript). Thanks for putting me on the right path.

Comment: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-8887